# getting the return value of curl_exec for the url with content type of text/xml

Tags: php, xml, curl, return-value

I have a web service which returns the out put in form of XML; but for a special method, the document says that it returns integer. for example I call it for getting the credit of the user for buying something. my method print the user credit but does not return the credit;

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        $username = "123456";
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => '$myurl',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
                         ));                       
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        echo nl2br($resp);
        //echo 
        if($resp > 100) 
            echo "TRUE";
        else 
            echo "FALSE";
```

I set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true but when I want to check the result with a number to allow the user to buy something, the $result variable as a 1 ( TRUE); I do not use https to set the other property such as CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER; 
in the code above it always echo the FALSE;
Do I parse the output or can you suggest another way to get the credit from the service?

Regards!

Comment: what you do you mean by this? `CURLOPT_URL => '$myurl',` is a string literal not an interpolated variables inside the string, just take that quotes out, it doesn't help your case

Comment: sorry just for security i changed it. it is a valid url for my web service ;)

Comment: oh okay, i thought it was literally like that, anyway, have you tried debugging curl itself? `echo curl_error($curl);`

Comment: it works great but the problem is just it show the output not return the out put. do I parse it?